# How to get POST requests through Nginx reverse proxy to Node/Express.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I have a typical Express.js app with a POST route.

I have nginx acting as a reverse proxy to the Express server.

nginx properly sends incoming requests, but seems to drop the POST request Body.

Here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffering off;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Turns out my nginx config was fine, the error was somewhere else in the app, but it appeared like a nginx error. The above config works totally fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out my nginx config was fine, the error was somewhere else in the app, but it appeared like a nginx error. The above config works totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with something like this?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Or maybe something more like this:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name yourdomain.com yourdomain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/yourdomain.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
```